# How to increase SeekBar scrolling touch position

Tags: android, scroll, seekbar

I have a `seekbar`.Normally when we scroll on `seekbar` `setOnSeekBarChangeListener` is fire.Now I want when we scroll anywhere on the screen `setOnSeekBarChangeListener` should be fire(So `seekbar` will be scrolled).Actually I'm not getting how to do this.So can any help me out.Thanks

Comment: You have to do it in touchlistner. now its on you. what u take background. as imageView or view (idk if we can attach touch listner on view.) and take touchposition and assign it to seekbar. but u have to convert that touch wrt 100%

Comment: Thanks for replay @Zohaib...can you please elaborate this...in brief

Comment: use this override method for touchevent

    @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           int x = event.getX();
           int y = event.getY();
           return true;
        }

now when you will click on screen you will have x and y axis. suppose you have 240px width and u have click it in centre than u will have x = 120. you can assign it to seekbar. and make your seekbar max value to max value of widht. or convert that x=120 wrt to 100 and than assign it to seek bar..

Comment: thanks @Zohaib I done it

Comment: If you are looking at this question because you have a SeekBar **embedded inside other scrollable views** and think that the SeekBar misses your "seek" touches and **scrolls the view instead**, I suggest you enable the "show touch events" in the developer settings of your device, so that you understand that it is not a problem of the size of the touchable SeekBar area, but that it has to to with the direction and the speed of how you attempt to initiate the seek action. It's not a problem of the size, but of the OS "touch-manager".

Comment: Thanks @DanielF I got to know after lot time spend U r right :)

Comment: @Dipu Were you able to solve this issue? I'm dealing with it right now. I'm thinking about intercepting the touch event (either by subclassing the seekbar or placing it in a custom view), so that it won't reach the layers below; will try that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this override method for touchevent `

```
 @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
 {  
  int x = event.getX();  
  int y = event.getY();
  return true;  
 }
```

now when you will click on screen you will have x and y axis. suppose you have 240px width and u have click it in centre than u will have x = 120. you can assign it to seekbar. and make your seekbar max value to max value of widht. or convert that x=120 wrt to 100 and than assign it to seek bar.